# Iterating a Buffer object via .map() and passing data to a component via props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my application I get a Buffer object with data from a file. For each byte in that buffer I want to render Bar and pass the byte as prop. However, the map function seems to have a problem with the Buffer object as Bar is not getting rendered at all. When I change data to an normal array everything works.

What am I doing wrong here?

````
import React from 'react';

function Bar(props) {
    return (
        <>
            {console.log(props.data)}
        </>
    )
}

function foo() {
  // var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  var data = new Buffer([0,1,2,3,4,5])
  
  return(
    <div>
       {data.map((a) => {
          console.log(a) //correct data here
          return <Bar data={a} />;
       })}
    </div>
  )
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

`new Buffer` does not return an `Array`. It returns an `Uint8Array`. Even if `Uint8Array` actually has a `.map` function in it's prototype, it will not get rendered properly by React.

Just convert it into an `Array`.

```
const data = [...new Buffer([0,1,2,3,4,5])];
```

or

```
const data = Array.from(new Buffer([0,1,2,3,4,5]));
```

**Note**: mapping over an `Uint8Array` still returns an `Uint8Array`, that's why nothing gets rendered. React render **does not** accept `Uint8Array`.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons your code is not working is because map callback method on Buffer (`Uint8Array`) is supposed to return another `Uint8` as a result but as you are not returning `Uint8` value, it assumes default value, 0.

I wouldn't explain in much details, but you can run following snippet to understand inner working of map function on `Uint8Array`.

```js
const uint8 = new Uint8Array([25, 36, 49]);
const mappedArray = uint8.map(i => 'a');

console.log(mappedArray);
```

You can fix this issue in your code by iterating through buffer beforehand and preparing an array of react elements you want to render like following:

```js
function Bar(props) {
  return (
    <span>
      {props.value}
    </span>
  )
}

function Foo(props) {
  const data = new Buffer([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  const items = [];

  for (const [index, value] of data.entries()) {
    items.push(<Bar key={index} value={value} />);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {items}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the `Buffer` class has a method `map()`? JavaScript arrays are objects of the `Array` class, which has [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. The `Buffer` class is probably lacking such a method. You can either iterate over the Buffer manually or implement a similar method for the `Buffer` class.

Comment: If Buffer doesn't implement the map() method why do I not get a compile error about an unknown function? And I get the right result in the console.log()...

Comment: It's not a `Buffer`, it's a `Uint8Array` and `Uint8Array` actually has `.map` function.